# Tag synonym and renaming proposals

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At some point we should be creating tag synonyms, as soon as we have users with enough reputation or some pro-temp moderators. We should start to collect possible synonyms and discuss them.

If you have an idea on a synonym or want to rename a tag to something better, please put your proposal in one answer to this question. Please add also a short justification for the synonym.

Please upvote synonym- or renaming proposals that you agree with and downvote proposals you disagree with.

Answer (score 4):

[food](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) and [nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) should be combined. They don't mean exactly the same thing, but I don't think we can manage to apply them accurately enough that the distinction would be useful.

I propose to make [food](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) a synonym of [nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition).

Answer (score 4):

[placebo](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/placebo) should be a synonym for [placebo-effect](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/placebo-effect), the same for [nocebo](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nocebo) and [nocebo-effect](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nocebo-effect).

We don't need both forms of the tag and I find the [placebo-effect](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/placebo-effect) and [nocebo-effect](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nocebo-effect) tags clearer.

Answer (score 3):

[alt-medicines](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alt-medicines) should be renamed to [alternative-medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-medicine), it is clearer, easier to find via search engines and the plural is not necessary in the tag.

Answer (score 2):

[9-11](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/9-11) and [september-11](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/september-11) should be combined (probably the latter should be a synonym of the former), as they clearly refer to the same topic.

Comment: I merged them and created the synonym

Answer (score 1):

Blood should be replaced with blood-type. By itself, it doesn't refer to a specific kind of woo.

Comment: Most of the [blood](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood) questions aren't about blood-type. There is a [blood-type](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood-type) tag too.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that both [movie](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) and [movies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies) exist. Can/should they be combined?

Comment: Done. I chose movies as the main tag, but that is easily reversed.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

We have tags for cars and automobile, which should be synonyms.

Comment: I merged automobile into cars and created a synonym.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed we have [microwave](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microwave) as well as [microwaves](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microwaves).

Comment: There was only one, closed, question that used "microwaves". I edited it, and didn't bother with a synonym.

Answer (score 1):

We have [colors](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) and [colour](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colour), these should be combined.

Comment: I merged colour into colors and created a synonym.